# How to create, edit or delete entities from a table and save it to database

Tags: javascript, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony5

I want to be able to use a table like this:

[Snippet 1](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=table-with-add-and-delete-row-feature)

[Snippet 2](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/temp/2863439?action=prism_export#!)

After editing, creating or deleting rows, I want to be able to submit them to the controller. After having the data in the controller I should be good and know what to. However my problem is how to send the dynamic information to the controller.

Any sugestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I've understood your problem, you need to use Ajax requests fom your Javascript code to controller. Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.update', function () {
that = $(this);
$.ajax({
  url:"/post/update",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {   /* here you collect your data from page */ 
           "name": that.parent.children('.name-input').val()     
  },
  async: true,
  success: function (data)
  {
    console.log(data);
    $('div#ajax-results').html(data.success);
  }
});

return false;
});
```